# Почему после добавление google services executePendingBindings не работает?

Tags: android, auth, google-play-services, android-data-binding

Я хочу добавить в проект `google sign in` и для это добавил зависимость:

в `app gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
```

В `project gradle`:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

После этого `executePendingBindings()` `not resolved`.
В чем может быть причина и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Clean and Rebuild` не помог.
Ответ сам нашелся...
После перезапуска `IDE`!

Comment: Так а первое правило разработчика - "перезагрузиться" никуда не исчезло и не исчезнет.